# Trying to solve error why text div isn't visible?

Tags: jquery

I must have done a very simple and stupid error in my script, but despite search and testing, I can't find it on my own and I seek for som help to solve it.

I have several articles on a page and if the width of the viewport is greater than 800px, the text should be visible. And if it's less than 800 px it should be unvisible and an icon to expand should appear. But when I have full screen over 800 px, the text isn't visible, but it's working if I'm resizing the viewport!? please ask if my question needs more explanation! I have added a `alert` to check whats happen. and the text is visible untill I press the button. What happens then?!

It's the `.text` that I want to show.

Part of the HTML code

```
<article>
<header>
    <img src="image.jpg" alt=""/>
        <div class="articleContent">
            <div class="imageTextContainer">
            </div>
            <h2>H1</h2>
            <div class="text">
            <p>
            Text here
            </p>
            </div>
            <div class="articleContentArrow"></div>
            <div class="plus"><a href="#"><img src="plus.png" /></a></div>
        </div>
</header>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".text").show();

var windowSize = $(window).width();

if(windowSize < 800){
    // Show menu button
    $(".mobileMenuButton").show();
    // Hide main menu
    $(".mainMenu").hide();
}

else if(windowSize > 800) {
    $(".text").show();
    $(".plus").hide();
    alert("Test");
}

// What to do when window rezise
$(window).resize(function() {
var win = $(window).width();
responsiveAction(win);
});

function responsiveAction(width) {
    if(width <= 830) {
        $(".mobileMenuButton").show();
        $(".text").hide();
        $(".plus").show();
        $(".mainMenu").hide();
    }
    else {
        // Hide menu button
        $(".mobileMenuButton").hide();
        // Show main menu
        $(".mainMenu").show();

        $(".text").show();

        $(".plus").hide();
    }
}
// Click
$(".mobileMenuButton").click(function(){
    $(".mobileMenu").slideToggle("fast");
});
});
```

Comment: Where is mainMenu defined in your HTML?

Comment: In what browser are you facing the issue? Seems to work fine here http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/NsWAp/

Comment: Thats in another part of the HTML/PHP code.

Comment: so your issue is that your text is showing on load of the page if the screen is < 800 pixels?

Comment: No it's not showing onload, just when I'm resizing the window until I get below 800 px, then the text is hidden a icon is visible so the user can click on it to expand the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Fixing the JS

You are duplicating code to in two places to do the same function.  This introduces unneeded complexity (and the two functions are not quite the same).

Try to follow **DRY** principals (Don't Repeat Yourself).  See more about DRY [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/curlys-law-do-one-thing.html).

Replace this:

```
if(windowSize < 800){
    // Show menu button
    $(".mobileMenuButton").show();
    // Hide main menu
    $(".mainMenu").hide();
}

else if(windowSize > 800) {
    $(".text").show();
    $(".plus").hide();
    alert("Test");
}
```

...with this...

```
responsiveAction(windowSize);
```

This worked for me.  [See a fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/gG9A2/)

## A better way - Media Queries

Note that while the previous changes fix your code it is not the best way to approach this.  What you are trying to achieve is called **[Responsive Design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/)** and the appropriate method is to use css media queries.

> CSS Media queries allow you to target CSS rules based on - for
>   instance - screen size, device-orientation or display-density. This
>   means you can use CSS Media Queries to tweak a CSS for an iPad,
>   printer or create a responsive site.

Read more at [cssmediaqueries.com](http://cssmediaqueries.com/)

To adjust your site to use media queries do the following:

Reduce your js down to only the following...

```
// Click
$(".mobileMenuButton").click(function(){
    $(".mobileMenu").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Then in your css file...

```
.mobileMenuButton,
.plus {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 799px) {
  .mobileMenuButton,
  .plus {
    display: block;
  }

  .mainMenu,
  .text {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

[See a fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/gG9A2/3/)

This will achieve the same function as the previous js but by using native media queries you will reduce the js load and keep your code tidier.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working! When I reload the broswer(FF or Chrome) there is not text visible!? :(

Comment: Remember that in a fiddle the windowSize will be from the small area that the output is shown in.  Did you want your text to be invisible on page load for widths less than 800?

Comment: No, I want the text to be visible if the width of the viewport is greater than 800 px on page load. If it's less then 800 px I want to hade the text to minimize the content on mobile devices.

Comment: It's late here, I have to jump to bed and continue with this tomorrow! Thanks so far. :)

Comment: That is what I was asking.  It is also what the code above does.  See the fiddle.

Comment: Hi again! Thanks reply and info. Yes, I'm also using Media Queries to get a responive design, but I guess it's better to use the Media Queries. I had another jQuery  script that caused the text to be invisible. But I still have some problems with this other script. When the webpage is below 800px and the text in the articles are hidden and I click on the plus sign to unhide the text with slideToggle it's fine, but then when I resize the window to a larger screen size, the text won't be visiable!? What could be the reason for this? Precieate some help here.

Comment: I would need to see your code.  Perhaps start a new question?

Comment: OK! I post a new question later. Thanks so far!